# Registering for Apple Push Notifications and Entitlements.plist

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, code-signing-entitlements

I need to register my app for push notifications and put inside

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

implementation this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Now I got error like that

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment'
>   entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x26e320
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string
>   found for application}

I put aps-environment key inside Entitlements.plist with the value "development" but now I get error during running the app on iPhone like that:

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing
>   Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning
>   profile.

What am I doing wrong? I have updated my AppID on developer.apple.com for using push notifications in development, remove existed from Xcode and update the new one.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you selected the Development Provisioning Profile in your Build Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your entitlement-changes and sign you app with a certificate that has apn-enabled.